# Cannot save PDF for Excel file to SharePoint - Error 1004 Document not saved

Tags: excel, vba, pdf, sharepoint-2010

I created macro that save PDF to SharePoint library. It works for me but for end users not. When they run macro there is "error 1004. Document not saved"

I check permission in SharePoint and other things. I had this error only one time, now all the time it works for me. This is the code showed after debugging.

```
PrintRange.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, FileName:= _
Sheets("Settings").Range("B2") & Sheets("Settings").Range("B1") & ".pdf", Quality:= _
xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
OpenAfterPublish:=True
```

B2 cell is adress for SharePoint library, B1 is specific name for this file

Comment: Does Sheets("Settings").Range("B2") contain a UNC or network share address?

Comment: it was network adress like this: https ://servername.com/sites/X/Y/library/

Comment: Do the end users have the same machine setups, Office versions and user permissions as you?

Comment: they have the same permissions like me. The difference is users have Excel 2007 I have Excel 2010. They turn on excel setting in trust center and other.

Answer (score 1):

A bit late to the party.

I had this happen to me. Turned out that I had checked out the file that my macro was trying to overwrite. Once I checked it in on SharePoint, everyone could overwrite it without any issues. Give that a try!